# Creating a faux "context" in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

When Ember iterates over a collection of objects and outputs them to a page, say a list of links in a sidebar, Ember creates a context for each element. When that item is clicked Ember passes that element as context to the method.

How can I create a fake version of that context at will? I essentially would like to reuse a method that is currently receiving context from an onclick event.

Comment: Could you whip up a quick jsfiddle of what exactly you're trying to do? I think I get it, but I'd like to make sure before I tell you something incorrect.

Comment: I can do better than that:
http://andymatthews.net/code/PM/ 

My question works two ways. Add a client, then I want that client to be the "currently selected". In my thoughts I'd pass a fake context into my loadProjects method. Same when you add a project...it's not showing up so since I already have the newly created project I could pass that in as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand the question, but will give it a shot.  I think what you are trying to accomplish can be done by just setting the context straight up and probably should ignore the view.

```
clientsArray
....
    loadProjects: function(view){
        this.set('currentClient', view.context);
    },

    _setProject: function(){
        console.log('loading projects');

        var context = this.get('currentClient');
        PM.projectsArray.set('content', []);
        PM.projectsArray.pushObjects(context.get('projects'));
    }.observes('currentClient')
....
```

Then in your 'addProject' method just set the 'currentClient' (in clientArray) to the new context (your 'project' object).  The observer will pick that up and take care of the rest.  Being able to observe a value for change and update context accordingly is one of ember's strengths; it prevents you from needing to do a lot of the explicit work.  It is meant to keep you from needing to write all the bootstrapping code yourself, the the framework do the work.  Making a fake view would just complicates the code.

Comment: I personally don't find a site nearly as useful as a fiddler because I can't simply modify the code and hit run like I would normally do.  Plus when writing a fiddle you can cut the code down to a very specific problem and don't need to worry about the extra overhead of everything else going on around the site.